# Combine multiple columns without considering NA's

Tags: r

Below is the dataframe

[image]

I want to create 6th column where all the values of the 5 columns are combined. If a column has NA or 0, it shouldn't be considered.

There should be a space between each variable combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
 df1$X6 <- apply(df1, 1, FUN=function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse=" "))
```

Comment: Thanks...but the output is like this "bike_335, ball_514, coal_70". I want like this "bike_335 ball_514 coal_70" with no commas.

Comment: @MohanChakradharVedurupaka  I changed the code